# How to display content (HTML) based on route paramater in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm new to Laravel and i'm working in a e-commerce application. In this app, it is needed to display all products in different pages (1, 2, 3, ... etc). The routes are: /products/1, /products/2, etc. I'm currently using the pattern of showing 10 products per page.

For example, if there are 31 products, there will be 4 pages (4 buttons in the bottom of the page).

1st page -> 10 products;

2nd page -> 10 products;

3rd page -> 10 products;

4th page -> 1 product;

My question here is how do I iterate in the database and spread these products in their respective routes. What I've done so far (using blade):

```html
@extends("template")

@section("content")

  @for($i = 0; $i < $number_of_buttons; $i++) <!-- iterate trough the number of buttons -->

    @for($k = 0; $k < $NUMBER_OF_PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE; $k++) <!-- iterate trough all the products, but showing only a quantity of {{$NUMBER_OF_PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE}} products per page -->
      <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-6">
       <img src="{{$products[$k]->image}}" class = "img-responsive" alt = "{{$products[$k]->name}}">
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6">
       <h2>{{$products[$k]->name}}</h2>
       <p>{{$products[$k]->description}} </p>
          <p>{{$products[$k]->value}} </p>
          <a href="/details/{{$products[$k]->id}}" class="btn btn-default">Details</a>
     </div>
      </div>
    @endfor

  @endfor

@stop
```

The logic itself seems kinda wrong, but how do I insert into each route the products? In the example above, all routes will have the same number of products. I want to know how do I especify in this code what each route will receive, if it is possible. If i'm not being clear enough, please let me know.

Comment: Are you asking about [Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination)?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I think that's what I needed. I'll give it a look and see if it answers my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination I think you are overthinking this. instead of Products::get() do Products::paginate(10) in the controller then at the bottom of the blade on the bottom do {{ $products->links() }}  it will paginate automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Pagination is exactly what I was looking for. I spent time thinking a logic to display all the products in pages lol. As i said I'm new to laravel therefore I did not know this method. Thanks @Ohgodwhy and @Scott

Answer (score 0):

in your controller

```
    $products = Product::paginate(10);
    return View::make('pagination', compact('products'));
```

in your template

```
@extends("template")

@section("content")
        @foreach($products as $product)
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <img src="{{$product->image}}" class = "img-responsive" alt = "{{$product->name}}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <h2>{{$product->name}}</h2>
          <p>{{$product->description}} </p>
          <p>{{$product->value}} </p>
          <a href="/details/{{$product->id}}" class="btn btn-default">Details</a>
        </div>
      </div>
        @endforeach
      <div class="pagination"> {{ $products->links() }} </div>
    @stop
```